# Pass current GameScene instance into a class called within GameScene

Tags: ios, swift, class, sprite-kit

I'm building a `PauseButton` class in my SpriteKit game, and I want to draw a label to the `GameScene` when it is activated. However, I'm required to instantiate the button outside of `didMoveToView` (right before it- in `GameScene`) so that I can access it more "globally" from the `touchBegan` method.

```
let pauseButton = PauseButton(theTexture: pauseButtonTexture,gameScene:GameScene)
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
```

Ideally I would be able to pass in the view by instantiating it within `didMoveToView` but as of now I don't know how to do this and also access it from the rest of the scene. That said, is there a way to pass in the current `GameScene` instance I'm working with so that I can do something like `gameScene.addchild(label)` from inside a method of my button class? I couldn't find anything useful on this, so any help would be great!

Comment: If you're passing the GameScene from inside a GameScene method, use `self`.

Comment: @phillipMills what is the argument type?? I get the error `Cannot convert value type of NSobject -> () -> GameScene to expected argument type GameScene` when I call `let pauseButton = PauseButton(theTexture: pauseButtonTexture, gameScene: self)` before `didMoveToView` within GameScene. and the init looks like: `init(theTexture:SKTexture, gameScene:GameScene){`. Thanks!

Comment: That seems to be saying that you're not calling it within a GameScene method.

Comment: Here's another question where someone is making the same mistake with `self`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961146/value-of-type-nsobject-viewcontroller-does-not-conform-to-specified-t

Comment: @phillipMills I'm putting it right above `didMoveToView` as shown in the question, so I guess it's not in a method. Do I need to have it in one? The reason I'm not even putting it in `didMoveToView` is because I want to access `pauseButton` from the other GameScene methods like `Touches` and having it global in GameScene like that is the only way I know how?

Comment: When you put it outside of a method, it executes before the object is initialized, so you don't have a GameScene object that you can use.  You can declare the object outside of any method (something like `var pauseButton: PauseButton?`) and then assign it a value later...inside a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically can do it 2 ways.

1) Just create the property like this

```
var pauseButton: PauseButton!
```

and than instantiate it in didMoveToView like so.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
     pauseButton = PauseButton(theTexture: pauseButtonTexture,gameScene: self)
     addChild(pauseButton)
}
```

2) Use lazy instantiation so you can do what you tried to do initially.

A lazy var in in simplest form allows you to use self without doing step 1.

```
lazy var pauseButton: PauseButton = PauseButton(theTexture: pauseButtonTexture,gameScene: self)

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
```

You could even do it like so to add more properties of this button all in the same spot.

```
lazy var pauseButton: PauseButton = {
       let button = PauseButton(theTexture: pauseButtonTexture,gameScene: self)
       button.zPosition = 200
       button.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
       button.alpha = 0.5

       return button
}()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        addChild(pauseButton)
}
```

Remember every SKNode/SKSpriteNode etc has a scene property. If your button class is a subclass of SKNode/SKSpriteNode than you can get its scene property and use the "as" operator to get a reference to GameScene without passing in the scene in the initialisation method.

e.g

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

       lazy var pauseButton: PauseButton = PauseButton(theTexture: pauseButtonTexture,gameScene: self)

       var someBool = false

       override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
            addChild(pauseButton)
            pauseButton.loadPausedLabel()
       }

       func someMethod() {

       }    
 }

class PauseButton: SKSpriteNode {

      func loadPauseLabel() {

            // Way 1, reference to current scene but not to specific class

            guard let scene = scene else { return } 
            // Scene property is optional and is nil until button is added to a Scene so add the guard check.


            scene.someBool = true      // NOT WORKING
            scene.someMethod()         // NOT WORKING

            let label = SKLabelNode(...
            scene.addChild(label)      // WORKING

            // Way 2, use "as" to cast to specific scene (e.g GameScene) so you can call properties/methods on it. This is the same as passing GameScene in the init method.

            guard let gameScene = scene as? GameScene else { return } 
            // Scene property is optional and is nil until button is added to a Scene so add the guard check.
            // The button must be added to the scene you are trying the as? cast with, in this example GameScene. 


            gameScene.someBool = true      // WORKING
            gameScene.someMethod()         // WORKING

            let label = SKLabelNode(...
            gameScene.addChild(label)      // WORKING
      }
}
```

As a tip, I would not add the pause label in the pauseButton subclass, I would add it from within the scene it self or from a pause menu subclass. 
Also I would not subclass each button, I would crate 1 class that can be used for all buttons in your game. You could create an enum with button names and pass that into the init method to distinguish between your buttons when they are pressed.

Your button subclass should only handle animations, textures etc. You can check out apples game DemoBots for an example.

Hope this helps

Comment: I was just looking back to this problem and wanted to know if you could explain using `var pauseButton: PauseButton!`? I know it has to do with optionals but I'm not fully grasping them conceptually. What's the difference between you writing a `!` or a `?` after the `PauseButton`?

Comment: Yeah of course, might have to split this into 2 comments. Basically the ! means you are unwrapping the var pauseButton property. So than when you instantiate it it in DidMoveToView you can just write things like pauseButton.position, pauseButton.zPosition . You are essentially telling the compiler that pauseButton is there so we are cool. Now if you would try to do something with the pauseButton before instantiating it you will get a crash because you broke the deal (!) of saying that pauseButton is always there.

Comment: On the other hand if you would use the ? you are telling the compiler, hey this pause button is there or maybe not there,. You would than need to write things in didMoveToView like so, pauseButton?.position, pauseButton?.zPosition etc. This way if you forget to instantiate it in DidMoveToView, you will Not get a crash trying the access the var pauseButton property later on, e.g touchesMethod. This come is very handy for type safety. Imagine you need to create some special boost button as well, that only shows in special occasions. Using the ? will make your code safer incase you make an error.

Comment: They are awesome once you get the hang of them, and will improve your code a lot. This is where things like guard and if let statements than come into place. In your case I would put all the setup code of the pauseButton into the lazy var like I showed you, and than just add it in DidMoveToView. Keeps your code nice and clean.

Comment: Okay that helps a lot, I'm gunna look around for some other good resources on optionals to better understand them. Also, when I tried adding that code to the class I received an error: `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'GamScene.Type'` for the line `guard let scene = GameScene else { return }`, any idea how I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You must have misspelled. It needs to be guard let scene = scene as? GameScene else  { return }

Comment: Weird enough that works, but then I get the error `Use of unresolved identifier 'scene'` on the second `scene` of that very same line. Is scene supposed to be recognized or should I call a specific scene like `GameScene` because that didn't seem to work either?

Comment: Your class needs to be a subclass of SKNode/SKSpriteNode. (class PauseButton: SKSpriteNode {...}. Like my example. The scene after the = is the scene property of a SKSpriteNode/SKNode (your button class)

Comment: Are you trying to put the guard statement into a property?

Comment: Oh yeah.. thanks a lot!!! I'm gunna play around with this some more and see if I can grasp some of the optional-related concepts.

Comment: yeah if let statements of guard statements will not work as properties. You can maybe try a lazy var, that should work if you want a reference like your pause button " lazy var gameScene: GameScene? = { return self.scene as? GameScene }()  " . That returns an optional tho. However its usually better design to have less of those global class properties , so if you have more func that need reference to gameScene than just copy the guard statement into the functions.