# Value of type NSObject -> () -> **ViewController does not conform to specified type ***Delegate

Tags: ios, swift-protocols

I am receiving the error below:

[image]

My protocol looks like this:

```
protocol RecorderDelegate {

  func finishedRecordingWithUrl(URL: NSURL)
}
```

Can someone explain why self is NOT conforming to the protocol when it appears that it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time you are setting self as reference, self does not exist. Try to set it later, let say viewDidLoad or make it lazy.

Btw make the reference on delegate weak, otherwise you are creating reference cycle and your view controller instance is never going to dealloc and will create memory leak.

Comment: If you could share a little code that would be great, thanks!

Comment: Make your property lazy weak var. That should fix your problem. Btw why are you creating this property? Do you have another function that calls your delegate method via this delegate property?